# Date of Birth Field in Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Exposed Date of Birth Field on Visualforce page. This is of Date type 
Its shows Historical dates only, can i have dating back to at least 1900.

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific about what you're after.  Tells us what you've tried and what aspect of it you're specifically stuck on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the code shown in the following post from developer force and it works perfectly.  Note though that if you are using it on a VF page, you must have showSidebar=true and showHeader=true for it to work

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008kzBIAQ

I have not used this one but it seems to be similar in function

http://setupforce.wordpress.com/2012/10/16/populating-a-historic-year-range-on-the-calendar-pop-up-in-salesforce-crm/

> **EDIT**

**Adding the code for the first link at request of @TestNS**

1) Go to Setup -> App Setup -> Customize -> User Interface. Here make sure the 'Show Custom Sidebar Components on All Pages' is checked.

2) Go to Setup -> App Setup -> Home Page Layouts. Make sure all your Home Page Layouts have the Messages & Alerts component checked.

3) Go to Setup -> App Setup -> Home Page Components. Here, click edit for Messages & Alerts. In the textarea, copy and paste the javascript code below and save (it can just go below your normal Messages & Alerts, won't show up on the actual page).

```
<script src="/js/dojo/0.4.1/dojo.js"></script>
<script src="/soap/ajax/11.1/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dojo.collections.Store");
dojo.require("dojo.charting.Chart");
dojo.require('dojo.json');
var arYears = getYears();
function swapYears(){
    // Contact Birth day
    if(document.getElementById('calYearPicker') != null) {
        var select = document.getElementById('calYearPicker');
        var curValue = select.value; 
        var parentx = select.parentNode;
        parentx.removeChild(select);
        select = document.createElement('select');
        select.size = 1;
        select.id = 'calYearPicker';
        select.name = 'calYearPicker';
        parentx.appendChild(select);
    }
    if(select != null) {
        for(x=0;x<100;x++) {        
            select.options[x] = new Option(arYears[x], arYears[x], false, false);
        }
    }
}
function getYears() {
    sforce.sessionId = getCookie('sid');
    sforce.connection.sessionId=sforce.sessionId;
    var out = [];
    // generate dates for the last 100 years
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
    try {
        for(x=0;x<100;x++) {
            out[x] = x+year-99;
        }   

    } catch(error) {
        alert(error);       
    }   
    return out;
}
dojo.addOnLoad(swapYears);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please paste the code if possible. As i dont have access to this sites from client location

Comment: Just added the code for the first link, hope that helps